# TOPLink SchemaManager functionality

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, orm, schema, toplink

I wanted to know how `SchemaManager` of toplink works. I have a `DataBaseSession` and I create schemamanger from it. I also have some mappings in toplink. So my question is:

Will `schemaManager.getColumninfo()` provide me with info about those columns too which are not related to my mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it just wraps the JDBC API, it does not use the mappings.

Comment: Wel that does not seem to be the case with my application.

Comment: does it have some kind of caching?